# Validate XML file using Java with an XSD having an include

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I need to perform xml validation on the xsd schema. xsd schemas are stored in a DB table. Many schemes are interconnected via import and include. I pass an array of schemas to the validation function. If only "import" is found in the xsd schema, everything works. If "include" - I get the error: "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element".

```
// p_schemasArr[] - xsd array. It has all the schemes that are connected via include and import. The array is sorted. The last one in array b includes all the previous ones.
// e - Total xsd schema. There can be many schemes (up to 130).
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Source[] sources = new Source[e];
for (int i = 0; i < e; i++) {
  sources[i] = new StreamSource(new StringReader(p_schemasArr[i]), "xsd_" + i);
}
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(sources);
Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
validator.validate(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xmlFileSource.getValue())));
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XERCESJ-1130 which is labelled as "unresolved".

I believe this will work as expected with the Saxon schema validator, at least if you set the appropriate options.